Explicit expression for an exponentially weighted integral
Given some $a>0$, let $f:[a,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be continuous (or smooth, if required) and let $F:[a,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be defined by
\begin{equation}
F(t)=\int_{a}^{t}f(\sigma)~{\rm d}\sigma.
\end{equation}
I would like to know wether the quantity
\begin{equation}
{\rm e}^{-F(t)}\int_{a}^{t}\frac{1}{f(\sigma)}{\rm e}^{-F(\sigma)}~{\rm d}\sigma
\end{equation}
is bounded from above on $[a,\infty)$. Or is there even an explicit expression for this integral?
So far, I have tried integration by parts but without success. Also, I noticed that the integrand can be written as
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{f(t)}{\rm e}^{-F(t)}=\frac{1}{\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}{\rm e}^{F(t)}}
\quad\text{or}\quad
\frac{1}{f(t)}{\rm e}^{-F(t)}=-\frac{1}{f(t)^{2}}\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}{\rm e}^{-F(t)}.
\end{equation}
The functions I have in mind for $f$ are of the form $f(t)=1/t^{r}$ for some $0<r\leq 1$. For each $r\leq 1$, it seems that the above integral is bounded as it can be shown by an explicit integration.

What do you get for $f(x) = (x-a)^n$?
